# Facebook Auth: What Authorized redirect URIs are required?

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have Social Login web application writed in Spring Social and Spring Boot.
My problem is about log in with facebook.

I get this response after log in:
[image]

Response contains access token, but it can not redirect to my address /userInfo, because some URL is not saved to VALID  OAUTH REDIRECT URI'S.

My settings on facebook for developers platform looks like this, below links to pictures:

[image: App Domains]

[image: Site URL]

[image: Valid OAuth Redirect URIs]

[Link to source code at github.](https://github.com/hubertstruminski/spring-social-youtube)

My question is as title. What configuration should looks like on facebook for developers platform?

I get this error in Spring console:

> Can not load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the application domains.

Comment: `localhost:443` is - of course - a local address. Facebook cannot access it.

Comment: @GrafiCode that is irrelevant, because Facebook does not have to access anything here to begin with. The relevant redirects happens inside the client browser, so that is the only one here that needs to be able to resolve this.

Comment: @misorude are you telling me `localhost:443` is a valid oauth redirect uri? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdH3E.png

Comment: @GrafiCode of course it is. Again: Relevant on the client side only, as long as only Facebook login is considered, and we are not talking about any advanced features like Webhooks (which actually require Facebook to connect to your server.)

Comment: @misorude I'll be damned :) thanks for the explanation

Comment: _“Response contains access token”_ - no it doesn’t … it contains a `code` parameter, and your app needs to exchange that code for a token via an API call in the next step. It looks like you are getting the error in that step, and that usually means, the `redirect_uri` parameter value passed in that API call was different from the one specified in the login dialog URL - they _must_ be exactly the same.

Comment: I don't see it. Can you show me answer ?

Comment: You are confusing what `redirect_uri` is for. This is used for security and to call back with the `code` to exchange. This URI must match both calls to Facebook. Once you have exchange the code for the access token, it is YOUR code that redirects the user to `/userInfo` and NOT Facebook.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?   client_id=455695445269575&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4443/userInfo&state={state-param}. That's good ? What insert to state-param ?

Comment: The purpose of `state` is to prevent CSRF attacks on the login process, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow It’s a random value, that you should store into your session, and compare with the one that gets passed back to your app afterwards.